# Unlocking all prefixed actions in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, routes

So I'm prefixing a bunch of actions for an API. I'm doing my own auth, and so I want to have all prefixed API actions `unlocked` and `allowed` by default.

Is there a simple, non-janky way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `beforeFilter()` method of `AppController` check the request object to get the prefix if there is one. If it matches `unlocked` or `allowed`, call `$this->Auth->allow()`.